# How can I prevent ogr2ogr from trying to get the SRID from PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr, performance

I'm running ogr2ogr for a PostGIS to GeoJSON export like this:

```
ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:4326 -f GeoJSON unique_geoms.json "PG:host=localhost dbname=local_data user=local_user password=local_pass" -sql "SELECT MAX(geom)::geometry FROM geom_table GROUP BY ST_AsBinary(geom)"
```

ogr2ogr isn't very bright, and tries this query on my database:

```
SELECT ST_SRID("max") FROM(SELECT MAX(geom)::geometry FROM geom_table GROUP BY ST_AsBinary(geom)) AS ogrpggetsrid LIMIT 1
```

So the database has to run the entire subquery to even get a response! This is fine for small tables, but for really big tables, the operation takes forever.

As you can see, I tried using `-s_srs EPSG:4326` to override the built-in SRID detection, but it doesn't work.

My query is designed to de-duplicate my point geometry. I could create a new table based on this query, but I'm not sure that would help.

Comment: Have you tried setting t_srs also? I know this might be a daft suggestion but I am also in the middle of a battle with ogr2ogr which is a great app, but with somewhat obscure docs

Comment: Yes, -s_srs and -t_srs should be used as a pait. If that does not work I would have a try by making a view from the subquery and registering the view into geometry_columns for arranging direct access to the metadata of the view.

Comment: I tried using `-s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:4326` together and  I can confirm it still hits PostGIS with `SELECT ST_SRID` ... @user30184 how do I register the view in geometry_columns?

Comment: Postgis documentation is often useful http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#Manual_Register_Spatial_Column

Comment: Yes, do you see this geometry in geometry_columns.

Comment: @user30184. Postgis documentation is often useful, I think that might become part of my epitaph.